# extending a linearly independent set to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that every linearly independent set in a finite-dimensional linear space can be extended to a basis for the entire space.

Comment: Good for you. You can find the proof in any reasonable linear algebra book. Did you have a question? (In case that came across as too snarky, the idea is to keep adding vectors, one by one, so that each new vector is not in the linear span of the ones you already have. If you can do it forever, the space is not finite dimensional. Otherwise, when you can't continue, you have your basis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every linearly independant set has at most $n$ elements in a vector space $E$ s.t. $\dim E=n$, if this set does not spans $E$ then there's $x\in E$ which isn't a linear combination of elements of this set so subjoin this element $x$ to the set and it remains linearly independant, we can repete this procedure until we have $n$ elements

Comment: I see, and since the set is finite dimensional, the procedure stops at some point.

Comment: The property asked in the question is usually a part of the proof that the dimension of finitely generated vector spaces is well defined (see the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma)). So using dimension in this answer is circular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some finite spanning set $S$ to witness that the space is finite dimensional. Then a procedure to extend a linearly independent family $F$ to a basis is to consider the sequence of vectors formed by listing $F$ and then $S$, and then for each vector in turn decide wither it is linearly dependent with its (remaining) predecessors in the list, in which case it is thrown out, or not in which case it is retained. One easily shows that all members of $F$ survive (by the linear independence between them), and that throwing out a vector does not change the span of the list of vectors, which therefore remains the whole space. At the end the whole list has become linearly independent, and therefore a basis.

See the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) for a somewhat more detailed statement, that will in particular show that if $S$ was in fact a basis, then the new basis computed by this procedure has the same number of elements as $S$, which in turn can be used to show that dimension a well defined notion for these spaces.