# Existence of a subspace with a certain property

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I am having trouble solving this problem.I have started solving the problem , so far my guesses for the subspace U were the intersection of V and complement of KerT , but i was soon able to come up with a counter example.

Then i made some modifications for U. My current guess for U is the following and i have proved that the intersection of U and Ker T is {0}.

[image]

I am not confident that my guess for U is correct.

Comment: What your counterexample in your mind? It seems to me, the complement satisfies the required properties.

Comment: @Taro the comlement does not contain $0$-- not a subspace.

Comment: @MorganO I mean complement as subspace. $V = \ker T \oplus U$. Not set-theoritic meaning.

Comment: @Taro yes, that's exactly what you want to do =) But judging by the OP's construction, I think they meant set-theoretic complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice first that $V \cap (V + (\ker T \cap \{0\}^c))^c=(V+(\ker T \cap \{0\}^c))^c$. This is because all sets are already contained in $V$, so the intersection is superfluous. For your proposed $U$, note that $V+(\ker T \cap \{0\}^c)=V$. Indeed, Given $x \in V$, choose $y \neq 0$ in $\ker T$. Then $-y \in V$. Hence $(x-y)+y=x \in V+ (\ker T \cap \{0\}^c).$ This shows that $(V+(\ker T \cap \{0\})^c)^c = \emptyset$.

In general, it is difficult to build subspaces by taking set-theoretic complements and removing points. A good way to get a concrete handle on problems like this is to work with a basis for your vector space. By choosing a convenient basis, this particular problem simplifies considerably.

Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ be a basis for $\ker T$; then you can [extend this set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372944/extending-a-linearly-independent-set-to-a-basis) to a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$ for $V$. Assume $\ker T \neq V$ (this case is easily dealt with separately), so that $k>m$. Let $$U=\langle e_{m+1},\dots,e_k \rangle.$$

From the fact that $e_i$'s form a basis, you can deduce that $U \cap \ker T= \{0\}$ and that $T(U)=\operatorname{Range}T.$ For proving the part about the image, the [rank nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) might also come in handy.

Comment: Note that $W$ is not a subspace of $V$. So you cannot extend a basis of $W$ to that of $V$. Perhaps what you intended is $\ker T$ instead of $W$.

Comment: @Taro yes, thanks for pointing that out.